# Apache beam with redis - select database and read from hash?

Tags: redis, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am starting out with Apache Beam, and I would like to read from a hash that I have stored in Redis, and I will also need to select the database (number).  I looked at the source of RedisIO, but it does not seem like it includes the ability to do either of these things.  Have I missed something, or am I going to have to write my own implementation to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, these parameters are not currently supported.

For now, the easiest way to do this would be to extend `RedisIO.BaseReadFn` and overwrite `setup` and `teardown`.